# An integer array of up to 10 integers is read. Negative integers are not allowed to read

Tags: arrays, c

My program only allows positive integers up to 200 to be entered. -1 and the rest of negative numbers are not allowed to be read, and for safety, the 10th digit is not allowed to be read, program should stop reading.
That is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int age[10] = {0}; // initalized an array
    printf("Please enter ages: "); // allow user to enter numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (age[i] == -1 || i > 9) { // if the element of is euqal to zero and 10th element
            printf("invalid number");
            break; // program stop
        }
        else if (age[i] < 0 || age[i] > 150 ){
            printf("It is invalid number, the valid number is bigger than 0 and smaller than 150");
            scanf("%d",&age[i]); // allow user enter again
        }
        else {
            scanf("%d",&age[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The major question is that my code not stop reading when i enter the negative number.

Comment: *`age[i] == -1 || i > 9) { // if the element of is euqal to zero and 10th element`* - that code definitely doesn't do what that comment says

Comment: *`smaller than 150");`*  vs *positive integers up to 200 to be entered* - I'm detecting a slight lack of attention to detail/precision.. As a general programming tip, do try to make everything consistent with the spec you lay out - you'll find computers don't tolerate imprecise instructions well and not being precise is a recipe for confusion for you when the program runs

Comment: Read the age into a temporary variable and check that. Use a loop to make sure that the user doesn't enter an invalid number *again*. I recommend you create a "get integer in range" function.

Comment: Also, *always* check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: This accepts 150, which is another mistake.  If this is about people, the maximum age of 150 doesn't make sense; set it to 120.

Comment: You should write a function that handles getting an integer between a lower and upper bound and returns it. This will clean up your main function considerably and make it easier to reason about your program.

Answer (score 2):

Your program doesn't work, because you check if the numbers are negative, before you actually read them. Also, you check if `i` is greater than 9, which is redundant, since the for-loop already checks that. Finally, when the user enters an invalid number, you shouldn't just `scanf` a new one, because they might enter an invalid one again: you should instead run another iteration of the loop with the same `i` (decrease `i` by one and `continue`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int age[10] = {0}; // initalized an array
    printf("Please enter ages: "); // allow user to enter numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("#%d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&age[i]); // allow user enter again
        if (age[i] < 0 || age[i] > 150 ){
            printf("It is invalid number, the valid number is bigger than 0 and smaller than  151...\n");
            i--;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This still accepts 150 as input, which is another mistake of the OP.

Comment: It accepts up to AND INCLUDING 150. If you want 150 to be invalid, replace `age[i] > 150` with `age[i] >= 150`.

Comment: Either that or fixing the printed text `the valid number is bigger than 0 and smaller than 150`.  Not your mistake eh.